# Object prototype not working in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, prototype

I have a bit of an issue when i try to create an object prototype in my node/express app.

I first start by creating the prototype like so:

```
Object.prototype.printObject = function () {
  return console.log(this);
}
```

Now the issue is when I call this function. For instance when i call the function like this:

```
let request = {1:2}
request.printObject();
*//Logs {1:2}*
```

No error occurs. Yet when I call the function like this:

```
let request = req.body
request.printObject();
```

My program crashes with error: `TypeError: request.printObject is not a function`

Does anyone have any clue as to why this occurs?

Comment: What's the value of `req.body`?

Comment: I hope you already know it is very bad idea to modify `prototype` property of any class that is not owned/written by you

Comment: The value is the body of the request as sent via Postman. In this case: `{email: "test@test.com', password: 'testing1234'}`

Answer (score 0):

if you require('body-parser')? or req.body is undefined,you should do this first

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser') 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
```

Answer (score 0):

Insteat of trying to prototype any Object, you could create a middleware function like so:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('req');
  //you could also add any function to req,even so thats not a common thing to do
  req.printObject = function { ... }
  next();
});
```

Probably the problem with your approach is, that you add the function to the Object prototype after the request object was created.(EDIT: This is wrong, see comments)

Comment: prototype are shared, so modify after object is created wouldn't be the issue

Answer (score 0):

You have added the 'printObject' method on the prototype of Object. So if req.body is an **Object**, you should be able to call the method.

Try checking the type of req.body using `console.log(typeof req.body)` to verify that it is an Object.

If it is not, you should use the node module 'body-parser' to populate `req.body` with the parsed body content.

For example, parts of your server code might look like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // Data is being sent to the server in JSON format

app.post('/my/endpoint', function(req, res){
    req.body.printObject();
});
```

The 'body-parser' module supports other formats as well. I used JSON as an example. You can find everything they support here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

Comment: i checked out the object type and it does indeed return that it's an object. also a console log of the object itself does return a JSON object with values.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the code that attaches the `printObject` method to the Object prototype is executed before you try to call it on `req.body`? Could you post a longer snippet of the code showing where exactly you're attaching the method to the prototype and where you're calling it?